# Vector operation modules in Python Standard Library?

Tags: python, vector, standard-library

I'm solving some competitive programming problems related to vectors, but I can only use modules from the standard library, I'm not sure if there is any module that defines vectors and vector operations. I intended to use a package from the standard library to avoid having to do the work of defining vector operations.

What module should I use?
... Or should i define by myself the vector operations I need?

Comment: Python doesn't, but could you use subprocess builtin module to execute different programs that do handle vectors better?

Comment: Pretty much everybody uses NumPy for that kind of thing. If you're limited to the standard library, you'll have to do it yourself.